# "error Cannot read property 'split' of undefined" in trying to execute react-native app

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, react-native, npm

Yesterday I could run a react-native app without any major problem, but today I tried to run it again. I run "npm start" to start metro and then I tried to run "npx react-native run-android" And then it started to return the following error:

```js
npm ERR! Cannot read property 'split' of undefined

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/brunno/.npm/_logs/2021-07-27T15_00_53_791Z-debug.log
```

As I opened the log so I could try to solve it, it dind't cleared it up anything to me.

---

```js
21 verbose stack TypeError: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
21 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/utils/path.js:4:23)
21 verbose stack     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
21 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
21 verbose stack     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
21 verbose stack     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
21 verbose stack     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
21 verbose stack     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
21 verbose stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/share/nodejs/npm/lib/exec.js:64:14)
21 verbose stack     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
21 verbose stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
22 verbose cwd /home/brunno/Documentos/ReactNative/exercicios
23 verbose Linux 5.11.0-25-generic
24 verbose argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/share/nodejs/npm/bin/npm-cli.js" "exec" "--" "react-native" "run-android"
25 verbose node v12.21.0
26 verbose npm  v7.5.2
27 error Cannot read property 'split' of undefined
28 verbose exit 1
```

Comment: please provide some details.

Comment: Can you post the code where you used `split` ? The object you are using it on is `undefined` for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

The thing is I didn't used the split anywhere is a brand new code,
and the error is happening when I try to launch the app through terminal, when I launch it through Android Studio it goes ok, without any issue

Answer (score 1):

I have just run into this myself. The problem is this code in `npm`:

```js
const PATH = (
  process.env.PATH || process.env.Path || process.env.path
).split(delimiter)
```

Which means that if there is no environment variable called `PATH`, `Path`, or `path`, then it will be trying to split an undefined variable. The simplest solution will probably be to just ensure that the `PATH` environment variable is defined, even if it's just set to the empty string.

My reason for encountering this situation was that I was setting a few environment variables when calling npx from python (via `subprocess`), and I hadn't included `PATH` in that set of variables.